# How to create unbound variable part of an array(a method param) in a method created by macros

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In a phoenix app, I'm trying to implement authorization like this

```
#= Bouncers.Bouncer.check_entry(conn, %MyApp.User{})
#=> true

defmodule Bouncers.Bouncer do
  alias Bouncers.Areas

  def check_entry(conn, resource) do
    verify(resource, conn.path_info)
  end

  defp verify(resource, path) do
    try do
      Areas.verify(resource, path)
    rescue
      _ -> false
    end
  end

end

defmodule Bouncers.Doors do

  defmacro bouncer_for(model, allowed_routes) do
    for route <- allowed_routes do
      quote bind_quoted: [route: route, resource: model] do
        def verify(resource, route), do: true
      end
    end
  end
end

defmodule Bouncers.Areas do
  require Bouncers.Doors
  import  Bouncers.Doors

  bouncer_for %MyApp.User{}, [
    ["api", "users"]
  ]
end
```

`bouncer_for` creates multiple `verify` method for a Struct and a `path_info` array

```
bouncer_for %MyApp.User{},  [
      ["api", "users"],
      ["api", "posts"]
]
```

will create

```
def verify(%MyApp.User{}, ["api", "users"], do: true
def verify(%MyApp.User{}, ["api", "posts"], do: true
```

It works for these `paths`, but I'm stuck at paths that are of the format `["api", "users", _ ]`, this  throws an error about unbound variable,. I would like to something like this atleast,

```
bouncer_for %MyApp.User{},  [
      ["api", "users", "*"],
]
```

And replace `"*"` with `_` inside the parameter of the method generated by the macro,. Any pointers?

Comment: Side note: If you already `import` a module, I think the extra `require` is not necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define your macro like this:

```
defmodule Bouncers.Doors do
  defmacro bouncer_for(model, allowed_routes) do
    for route <- allowed_routes do
      quote do
        def verify(unquote(model), unquote(route)), do: true
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then it should work as expected.

The reason for this is that `bind_quoted` will attempt to pass down the binding (i.e. actual values) to the macro, but `["api", "users", _]` is not a valid value in itself. It is rather a pattern, which you can embed in the dynamically generated function definition using `unquote`. This will behave as if you had written the pattern directly in the definition. To illustrate this problem, here is some code that is *roughly* equivalent to the definitions generated by the macros:

```
# using bind_quoted
@route ["api", "users", _]                    # invalid value, raises error
def verify(%MyApp.User{}, @route), do: true

# using unquote
def verify(%MyApp.User{}, ["api", "users", _]), do: true
```